# performance counter value of _total is less then single instance's value

Tags: powershell, performancecounter

My computer is a multi-core computer. When I tried to see some performance counters, I found a weird result: the value of "_total" is less then a value of a single instance.

```
PS > (get-counter -counter "\Processor(*)\% Processor Time").counterSamples

Path                                  InstanceName      CookedValue
----                                  ------------      -----------
\\hp\processor(0)\% processor time      0            1.56953777804887
\\hp\processor(1)\% processor time      1            1.56953777804887
\\hp\processor(2)\% processor time      2            6.25670264576083
\\hp\processor(3)\% processor time      3            1.56953777804887
\\hp\processor(_total)\% processor time _total       2.74132399533433
```

Look at:

> \hp\processor(2)\% processor time      2            6.25670264576083

and:

> \hp\processor(_total)\% processor time _total       2.74132399533433

"_total" is the sum of values of all instances. Then why is it not true here?

Thanks

Comment: Unlike Linux, Windows scales total CPU usage (not process-specific) to 0..100% range, meaning  the sum is divided by 4 in your case (you can confirm it with a calculator).

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you are using the wrong baseline:

> Now this Processor time counter under the Process Object gives the
>   amount of CPU this Process is taking individually. This value is
>   calculated over the base line of  (No of Logical CPUS * 100),  So this
>   is going to be a calculated over a baselin of more than 100.

[reference](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12984.understanding-processor-processor-time-and-process-processor-time.aspx)

your total processor time 10.9653159799074 is over 400, or roughly .0274, as a percentage is 2.74%

And this is entirely within the realm of the counter, and not a PowerShell manifestation in and of itself.

Comment: That quote is about `Process (%Processor Time)`, not `Processor(_total)\% Processor Time`.